# Rendering thumbnails of a GPX track with my own tiles as base layer

Tags: tilemill, image, rendering, gpx, thumbnail

I created my own Map using Tilemill. Now I'd like to display thumbnails of a GPX track where my map is the base layer.

Do you have any idea how to do this performantly? I wrote a script that does it using Tilemill but doing that for a couple thousand tracks would take forever...

I'd have all tiles pre-rendered anyway as either mbtiles or just as tiled pngs in folders...

Any ideas are very welcome :)

:: EDIT ::

If you could tell me a tool that takes a datasource (mbtiles or web) like https://github.com/vvoovv/tile-utils for example but that would be able to clip the result to the bounding box i specify rather than taking all the tiles that fit into the bounding box, I should be all set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool called gpx2png which is exactly what I needed!